# unterminated string literal error when creating json dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm trying to create a json variable to pass to slideshow plugin.this is the code in `head` section :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var photos = []; 
    {% for service in company.services.all %}   
        photos.push({
            "firstline" : "{{service.name}}",
            "secondeline":"{{service.description|truncatewords_html:50}}"
        });
    {% endfor %}
</script>
```

`service.description` contains html tags,using `description` cause this error:

```
unterminated string literal
```

Comment: I'm guessing those HTML tags also contains unescaped double quotes?

Comment: never build json by hand. you're suffering from the json equivalent of sql injection. always use native services, e.g. json.dumps to build your json.

Comment: your description probably has a `"` somewhere in there.  You should view source of the rendered page to see.

Comment: Try Escaping  the characters in description.

Comment: what do U mean by native services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`escapejs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#escapejs):

```
{{service.description|truncatewords_html:50|escapesjs}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably aren't escaping your quotation marks. `service.description`, being HTML, may contain some quotation marks. When you use django to just put it in the JS code, since django doesn't know *where* the string is going, it doesn't escape anything. Hence the "unterminated string literal".

Within your django code, *first* escape the special characters in the string with a backslash.